# How to most quickly check whether a given sentence is logically equivalent to $p↔q$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

This is from a Discrete Mathematics term test:

> Q4. Which of the following statements is/are logically equivalent to $p ↔ q$?
>
> (I) $(¬p \lor q) \land (p \lor ¬q)$
>
> (II) $(¬p \land ¬ q) \lor (p \land q)$
>
> (III) $(¬ p \lor ¬ q) \land (p \lor q)$
>
> (IV) $(¬ p \land q) \lor (p \land¬ q)$

The answer is (I) and (II).

As this is MCQ, I definitely avoid truth tables. I also want to avoid using a lot of equivalent laws, to save time and reduce sources of error.

I could easily get the first one since $p \iff q \equiv (p \to q) \land (q \to p)$.

However for (II), I cannot think of simple way other than applying distributive law into 4 terms like into $$((¬ p \land ¬  q) \lor p) \land ((¬  p \land¬  q) \lor q),$$ then another round of distributive law to simplify to $$((¬  p \lor p) \land (p \lor ¬ q)) \land ((¬  p \lor q) \land (¬ q \lor q)),$$ which feels very tedious to me especially since I might mess the ordering up since some of these properties might not be commutative.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: $p \iff q$ is true only when both $p$ and $q$ have the same truth values. It is fairly easy to see that option II satisfies  that.

Comment: So is the general idea to get the possible set of truth values that the original statement allows, for this case (p,q) only can be (T,T) and (F,F) , then do a substitution test to see whether it evaluates as True?

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth I've rewritten my (previously wrong) answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using double distribution : \begin{align}(\lnot p \land \lnot q)\lor(p\land q) &\equiv (\lnot p \lor p) \land (\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor p) \land (\lnot q \lor q) \\ &\equiv (\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor p) \\ &\equiv p\iff q \end{align}.

Hope that help!

Comment: That is what I wanted to avoid actually...

Comment: Only way I know how without using a logic table. Sometimes, this is consider as an equivalence for $\iff$.

Comment: I mean brute force is one thing, but I think I want to free up the carelessness factor during examination pressure

Comment: Yes, I understand, having done this course myself. Sometimes there kind of computation can get tedious, but this one is only three step. Anyway, sorry I couldn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

> > Q4. Which of the following statements is/are logically equivalent to
> > $p ↔ q$?
> >
> > (I) $(¬p \lor q) \land (p \lor ¬q)$
> >
> > (II) $(¬p \land ¬ q) \lor (p \land q)$
> >
> > (III) $(¬ p \lor ¬ q) \land (p \lor q)$
> >
> > (IV) $(¬ p \land q) \lor (p \land¬ q)$
>
> The answer is (I) and (II). As this is MCQ, I definitely avoid truth tables.
> I also want to avoid using a lot of equivalent laws, to save time and reduce sources of error, and feels very tedious. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

In propositional logic, sentence $S_{p,q}$ being logically equivalent to $(p ↔ q)$ means that $$(S_{p,q}↔(p ↔ q))$$ is a tautology. So:

1. first, plug the same value for $p$ and $q$ into each of the four options and eliminate the one(s) that evaluate as False;
2. next, plug different values for $p$ and $q$ into each of the four options and eliminate the one(s) that evaluate as True;
3. the remaining options are precisely the required sentences.